# how to close jquery dialog?

Tags: jquery

Please see below fiddle, I having a button inside dialog,

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/gD49Z/3/)

```
<input type="button" id="closePop" value="Close Dialog"/>
```

How to close the dialog by clicking "Close Dialog" button? thanks!

Comment: This is all explained in the [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) and [examples](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)...

Comment: could you please give me exact link, this is not jquery button buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach `click` event in open function of dialog

```
$('#closePop').bind('click', function(e) {
    jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/QJkVK/)

Answer (score 0):

You can close it programatically by calling:

```
$("#dialog").dialog('close');
```